# Syntax Error With Shell Script In AppleScript

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

I've got a script that runs fine in Terminal, but when I drop it into AppleScript, I get a Syntax Error.

The line in AppleScript is:

```
do shell script " tail -f -n+0 /vault/AppLog.txt | egrep '^\[Totals' "
```

Which gives me a Syntax Error:

```
Expected “"” but found unknown token.
```

And highlights the `[` before `Totals`.

What do I need to change for this to run smoothly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash to **\\**!

```
do shell script " tail -f -n+0 /vault/AppLog.txt | egrep '^\\[Totals' "
```

Have fun! Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thank you so much; I'm still starting out with AppleScript so I really appreciate this!